# Python fastest search in a list of tuple/list that returns the index

Tags: python, performance, list, python-3.3

I have a list/tuples of tuples/list (doesnt matter which one I use) where the value of the inner list or tuple has variable sizes. I need to check if a variable is in the first slot inner list or tuple.

> Structure looks like this:
>
> [ [[list of x amount of ints],[same number of ints as first slot],[[y number of ints], [z number of ints], .... , [a number of ints]], ... repeated about 20x]

Example:

> ([1, 21, 54, 55, 93, 99, 284, 393, 964, 1029, 1214, 1216, 1223, 1253, 1258, 1334, 1365, 1394, 1397, 1453, 1471, 1543, 1589, 1824, 1975, 2054, 2090, 2164, 2165, 2166, 2167, 2323, 2547, 2645, 2802, 2809, 2931, 2958, 3031, 3071, 3077, 3078, 3189, 3199, 3202, 3203], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2], [[3], [1], [4], [2], [12], [6], [3], [8], [20, 27], [11], [4, 7], [71], [133], [14, 74], [6], [67], [34], [3, 16], [9, 7, 23, 71], [11, 43], [67], [71], [4], [139], [16], [52], [4], [31], [7, 50], [2, 12], [1, 1, 83, 114], [13, 70], [60], [121], [30], [16], [214], [29, 78], [9, 37, 60], [14], [216, 249], [28], [2, 2, 21], [4, 18, 22], [59], [8, 24]])
>
> This is just the first value of my list of 20k+ elements that is similar.

So I have a function to check if a number is in:

> [1, 21, 54, 55, 93, 99, 284, 393, 964, 1029, 1214, 1216, 1223, 1253, 1258, 1334, 1365, 1394, 1397, 1453, 1471, 1543, 1589, 1824, 1975, 2054, 2090, 2164, 2165, 2166, 2167, 2323, 2547, 2645, 2802, 2809, 2931, 2958, 3031, 3071, 3077, 3078, 3189, 3199, 3202, 3203]

And it will return the index.

My function:
iD is the number I'm searching for, and posting is just the first element in my nest loop (the direct block above is an example of posting)

```
def searchCurrentPosting(iD,posting):
x = 0

for each in posting[0]:
    if iD == each:
         return x
    x += 1
return False
```

I have to run this search function every time a new word is given(20k to the power of some given number). This code will run for about a minute. Anyway to shave down the time?

Edit: If you want my whole program here it is:

This is my main driver: http://pastebin.com/Udjit7PP

File it parse is:  CACM collection which is the standard for IR testing.

Stemming used (port stemming): http://pastebin.com/AzA0fvdV

And Yes, I am creating an inverted index.

Comment: you don't know about the `list`/`tuple` method called `index`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you list at index 0 is sorted you can use [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/bisect.html) module to find the index in `O(log N)` time:

```
In [33]: import bisect

In [34]: lst = [1, 21, 54, 55, 93, 99, 284, 393, 964, 1029, 1214, 1216, 1223, 1253, 1258, 1334, 1365, 1394, 1397, 1453, 1471, 1543, 1589, 1824, 1975, 2054, 2090, 2164, 2165, 2166, 2167, 2323, 2547, 2645, 2802, 2809, 2931, 2958, 3031, 3071, 3077, 3078, 3189, 3199, 3202, 3203]

In [35]: n = 2802

In [36]: ind = bisect.bisect_left(lst, n)

In [37]: if lst[ind] == n:
    ...:     print 'Item found at {}'.format(ind)
    ...:     
Item found at 34
```

Note that if the list is not sorted then it'll be better to sort it first and store a reference in a variable so that you don't have to sort it again and again.

Another options is to use a dictionary, with the items as keys and index as values(for repeated items only the index of their first appearance will be stored i.e. similar to `list.index`). Once the dictionary is created than you can get an item's index on `O(1)` time.

```
In [38]: dct = {}

In [39]: for i, x in enumerate(lst):
    ...:     if x not in dct:
    ...:         dct[x] = i
    ...:         

In [40]: dct.get(n)
Out[40]: 34

In [41]: dct.get(1000) #return None for non-existent items
```

**Timing comparison:**

```
In [43]: lst = list(range(10**5))

In [44]: %timeit bisect.bisect_left(lst, 10**5-5)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 444 ns per loop

In [45]: %timeit lst.index(10**5-5)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.29 ms per loop

In [46]: %timeit dct.get(10**5-5) #dct created using the new list.
10000000 loops, best of 3: 104 ns per loop
```

---

In case if you're updating the list at index 0 continuously and it is not sorted as well then you should simply go for `list.index()` rather than using a loop, dictionary, or bisect.

```
In [47]: try:
    ...:     ind = lst.index(n)
    ...:     print 'Item found at {}'.format(ind)
    ...: except IndexError:
    ...:     pass
    ...: 
Item found at 34
```

Comment: What happens if ind = bisect.bisect_left(lst, n) doesn't find it? Does it return False or 0?

Comment: @MooingRawr  `bisect_left` simply returns the leftmost position where `n` can fit in `lst`. So, if `n` is not found then it will return the index of item that is greater than `n`, that's why need to check whether our list contains `n` at the index returned by `bisect_left`.

Comment: @MooingRawr Can you post your updated code in question body? I am not sure how it can still take the same amount of time since your original code was extremely slow compared to any of the methods I explained above.

Comment: @MooingRawr I don't think `searchCurrentPosting` is the function that is slowing down your code, you should try to profile other function as well. Also, you're using `bisect_left` incorrectly, it should be: `if poster[0][ind] != iD: return False`

Comment: That throws me a stack overflow. I'll look into bisect some more.

Also I've sped up my program by reading the whole file in or as much as I can at once. Still a bit slow but I'll tinker around some more. I wish I can just pm but not enough Rep. Oh well thanks fr helping